# Interface with multiple implementations and confusion about parameters

Tags: oop, inheritance, interface, abstraction

I have created the following interface:

```
public interface IReader
{
    string Read();
}
```

One implementation of it, is an XmlFileReader that encapsulates the logic to read xml files from disk based on a path stored in the config file.

Another implementation of it, is a FileReader that would read a file from disk based on the path specified as a parameter.

Now the confusion is that, the XMLFileReader doesn't require any parameter in the Read() method whereas the FileReader does. Should I add an optional parameter to IReader.Read() method, so that in the case of FileReader I can provide the file path using the parameter and in the case of XMLFileReader the parameter would not be used?

Another option could be to create a separate interface with a Read() method that takes the parameter.

What would be a good design for this scenario?

Comment: Why do you think two different calls should be same abstraction?

Comment: The reason being that it's the same operation i.e. read operation. The difference is whether the path is provided by the caller or extracted from the config. What alternative do you suggest?

Comment: If the parameters provided by caller are different, then they are different operations. Just because they are called same name doesn't make them same.

Comment: Another option would be to provide the parameter require for FileReader as constructor argument, which would effectively bind the implementation to a single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical solution is to put the parameters in the constructors of the concrete classes.

That said, I don't think your design is sound: what does return the `XmlReader.Read` method? Keep in mind that the user of an interface should ignore the concrete class it's using. So, after the call to `IReader.Read()`, it shouldn't do different elaborations on the string according to the type of the file. Is this your case?

It seems to me that the variation you want to capture is not the "Read the file" part, but the "How do I get the right file to read". In this case, an interface with a "Read" method is useless.

In any case: `IReader`, `XmlFileReader` and `FileReader` are really bad names for your classes. You should avoid -er suffix: see [this good article](http://www.carlopescio.com/2011/04/your-coding-conventions-are-hurting-you.html). And keep in mind that inheritance should model a IS-A relation.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use strategy pattern. It isolate the algorithms in separate classes in order to have the ability to select different algorithms at runtime.

Here is detailed description of pattern
[Strategy pattern explained](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html)

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: Yes I did see that, however it didn't make much sense in my scenario. Thanks anyways !